# I have a dropdown that contains two options, 'Approved', 'Denied'. I need to keep count for each option

Tags: javascript

This is what I have tried so far...I have to containers 'QuickClose_Approved and QuickClose_Denied. It counts the first occurence, but not subsequent selections.

```
if(ev.TableandFieldName=="ExtendedFields.Rush2ActionTaken")  {

var count = 0
var counter = count+1

if(los.GetField("ExtendedFields.Rush2ActionTaken")=="Approved") {
los.SetField("ExtendedFields.QuickClose_Approved", counter)
}
if(los.GetField("ExtendedFields.Rush2ActionTaken")=="Denied") {
los.SetField(ExtendedFields.QuickClose_Denied", counter)
}
};
```

Comment: Good coders indent their code properly. You also have unbalanced quotes. You always reset `counter` to zero, so that `count = count+1` will always make `count` equal to 1 and nothing else.

Comment: I apologize for coding errors. I was thrown into this and have no experience in javascript. Just trying to figure it out as I go. I changed count to 1 and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var counter = 0

if(ev.TableandFieldName=="ExtendedFields.Rush2ActionTaken")  {

  var counter = counter + 1

  if(los.GetField("ExtendedFields.Rush2ActionTaken")=="Approved") {
    los.SetField("ExtendedFields.QuickClose_Approved", counter)
  }
  if(los.GetField("ExtendedFields.Rush2ActionTaken")=="Denied") {
    los.SetField("ExtendedFields.QuickClose_Denied", counter)
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful to provide an explanation on how your code helps solve the problem.